# General solution using Integration

Tags: integration, differential

I have a DE like this,

$$X'' - 4a^2X = 0$$

and its solution is

$$X = c_1 \cosh 2ax + c_2 \sinh 2ax$$

Now, I want to know in detail how would I get this solution. I need all the steps to get the solution which I mentioned here.

Comment: Google `solving second order differential equations` and you will get $21.1$ million answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=e^{mx},X'' =?$

$m=\pm2a$

So, $X=Ae^{2ax}+Be^{-2ax}$

Now $\cosh(y)\pm\sinh(y)=?$

Comment: from where `cosh , sinh` come ?

Comment: @Abdur, are you aware of hyperbolic function s? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Comment: I know cosh = (e^x + e^-x) / 2 but here denominator is not equal to 2. And also, from where sinh comes ?